# How do I provide the correct permissions for a Github Workflow?

Tags: github-actions, devops

I have a GitHub runner installed on an on-premise Windows Server 2016 that pickups up a Github action workflow.  I installed the Runner as NETWORK SERVICE and have tried running it as other users out of desperation (Administrator, Local Service, Local System).  Regardless of what user I have tried thus far, I get the following error:

> ERROR ( message: The W3SVC service is not available - try starting the service first. )

I have verified that the service is running, and I am able to run the same command I have in my Github YAML file successfully from PowerShell on the on-premise machine.  I have included the line from my YAML file below.

```yaml
- name: Stop IIS Site and Pool
  run: 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe stop site "ORXApi1"'
```

Comment: Have you verified that the firewall is not blocking access over the network and that other similar network issues are already resolved?

Comment: @Azeem The firewall is not an issue.  This seems like a permissions issue.